# MYSQL Comment Counting, not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

Having an issue in MYSQL comment counting for individual posts, basically the following code is just counting all the comments as one post and assigning it to just one post_id:

```
    SELECT posts . * , COALESCE( COUNT( comments.post_id ) , 0 ) AS numberOfComments
    FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.post_id
    AND posts.number_of_comments = 'B'
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image: table: posts]

[image: table: comments]

These above are the tables, and the code's result is: 
[image: query result]

So I just want to count the number of comments for each posts and within mysql I don't want to make an additional PHP page to do so. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **GROUP BY** clause to count the post wise number of comments.

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(COUNT(c.post_id), 0) AS numberOfComments
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE p.number_of_comments = 'B'
GROUP BY p.post_id
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: This works! A question, how do I keep this updated? this works on SQL but it doesn't update within the table and I want MYSQL to do it automatically, obviously not via a php but if there's no choice then PHP it is, and thanks!

Comment: Okay I tried but I can't get it to work with triggers, can you please tell me more about it or give me code? Thanks